# Gradle 1.11 androidTest classes not running

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

So I've set up a gradle project with android and tried to get some tests to run. Unfortunately they don't seem to. It's possible that I'm missing something obvious but here goes...

I am running gradle 1.11 and as I understand the documentation that's the new folder (since 0.9 I believe?) that should be used for tests.

So I have my testclass ::

```
package se.coinhunter.multigradle.test;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class HelloAndroidTests {

   @Test
   public void testHelper() {
         assertEquals(1,1);
      }
   }

}
```

That lives in `src/androidTest` and here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':MultiGradleSubmodule')
}
```

This is a multi-project build and the submodule mentioned in the dependencies block is a plain java project that has its' own scource and unit tests running quite smoothly. I was able to specify that it should tell me when it runs its' tests and give me some feedback and that works fine. That was achieved for that project using

```
test {
    testLogging {
        events 'started', 'passed'
    }
}
```

in its' build.gradle. I havn't come across anything like this for android projects. The whole project builds and runs, but I either can't get the tests to run, or they're running but I'm not getting any output.

Answer (score 0):

You're using jUnit 4 (package name "org.junit" with @Test annotation).  Android gradle only works with jUnit 3 (package name "junit.framework" with no annotations).

Android tests run in the Dalvik virtual machine on a device or emulator so your test class should also extend "AndroidTestCase" (or one of the other junit subclasses in Android - depending on what you're testing).

UPDATED: also add the following to default config:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"

testFunctionalTest true
```

Run the test using

```
gradle connectedCheck
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As of right now I just need to run some simple unit tests to confirm that the logic of support classes and the like work as they should. I changed the class to extend AndroidTestCase and I removed the org.junit imports and replaced with junit.framework as you suggested. It's still building fine, but it looks like it's not running the test when i do gradle clean build. The build task should do both assemble and test so there must be something else I'm missing..

Comment: @Coinhunter - it wasn't clear from your post but are your test classes in "src/androidTest/java"?  Your post seemed to suggest that they might not be in the "java" directory under "androidTest".  You may also need to change "defaultConfig" by adding testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
       and testFunctionalTest true.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, I could probably have made that a bit clearer. The test is in src/androidTest/java indeed. I added the two lines you mentioned but nope, still building fine but without giving me any indication that the tests are in fact, running.

Comment: In case it helps, here's the link to the experimental repository:
https://github.com/Coinhunter/MultiGradle

Comment: @Coinhunter - in my environment "gradle build" does not run the tests.  You have to do "gradle connectedCheck".  Also, thanks for the link to the repo - I'll check it out.

Comment: That's correct `gradle build` does not run the test on devices because it requires a connected device. `build` (and `check`) will run lint and whatever else is supported that doesn't need a device (not much yet, but we'll have more later). You do have to use `connectedCheck` with a connected device (or more).